# How can i set thickness of horizontal rule in html

Tags: html, css

How can I set thickness of a horizontal rule in html/CSS

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use the `SIZE` property:

```
<hr size="3" />
```

Please note that this is deprecated.  You should really use styles to resolve this.

```
hr {
    height: 3px;
}
```

Comment: i want to set thikness to 4 px

Comment: @Stephan Muller: It's really hard to change `3` to `4`.

Answer (score 13):

If you have a lot of `<hr />` in your document, just add a style in your `<head>` section

```
hr
{
    border: 5px solid #000;
}
```

and change the **5px** to whatever you want.

**edit** Dont use height, it will make your hr look hollow, unless thats what you are looking for.

here is a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/ErdXg/
try out some colors and thickness and play around with it.

Comment: What if the OP wants an empty horizontal rule?

Comment: I know this solution is soft of a trick. But for me hr is a black line and not a hollow rectangle. And I want it thick! So this satisfies me most.

Comment: Nice! Taking it further: <hr style='border-top: 1px solid lightgray;' />

Answer (score 1):

Including Firefox:

```
hr {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #9b9b9b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS, like this:

```
hr {
    height: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for other examples of the HR attributes go [here](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tutorials/html/html_reference_guide_the_hr_tag.php3)

Answer (score 0):

```
<hr height="3" style="color:purple;background-color:purple;"></hr>
```

thats it hehe just change the background color thats it.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.cool_line{ 
    display:block;
    border:none;
    color:white;
    height:1px;
    background:lightgray;
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, 50% 50%, 0, 50% 50%, 350, from(lightgray), to(#fff));
}
```

```html
Begin

<hr class='cool_line' />

End
```

Comment: That is a cool line indeed, but it hardly answers the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the height doesn't work for me anymore as suggested in other answers (at least not working on Chrome 79), instead I've tried this and it works:

```
.thickhr{
  border:0.1rem solid black;
  height:0;
}
```